# How to make a shape have solid color that is 50% alpha of an already defined color?

Tags: android, android-view, android-resources, android-styles, android-color

I have a shape defined in a drawable resource file that I use as a background for my TextViews (scrim_background.xml):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

My colors.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


    <color name="white">#fff</color>
    <color name="light_text">#dfff</color>

    <color name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</color>

    <color name="colorAccent">@color/accent</color>


    <color name="primary">#F44336</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#D32F2F</color>
    <color name="primary_light">#FFCDD2</color>
    <color name="accent">#607D8B</color>

    <color name="accentAlpha">#DD607D8B</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
    <color name="secondary_text">#757575</color>
    <color name="icons">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="divider">#BDBDBD</color>

</resources>
```

The styles for my textviews is:

```
<style name="BeerItemTextStyleTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_text</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/scrim_background</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">start|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/space_small</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/space_small</item>
    </style>
```

I want that the background color to have 50% transparency of the colorAccent.

Something like:

```
<color name="accent">#88607D8B</color>
```

But I don't want to fix these values because I'm constantly changing the color scheme.

I tried to add alpha directly to my TextView, like:

```
<item name="android:alpha">50</item>
```

But it was not appropriate as it add the transparency to Text Color as well. I would like that only the background color were transparent.

I would not like to do this programmatically, because this way I would have to find all my textviews and change one by one.

-- EDIT --

I tried to create a meta resource file named bitmap_scrim_background that is:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/scrim_background">
        </bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>


<style name="BeerItemTextStyleTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_text</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bitmap_scrim_background</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/space_small</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/space_small</item>
</style>
```

But i think things doesn't work this way in Android... It throws:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class TextView

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #5: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this to create scrollbar thumb 50% transparent with existing non transparent color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:tint="@color/color_white_alpha_50"   //#80FFFFFF
    android:tintMode="multiply">
    <solid android:color="?colorControlNormal" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the scrim background is a drawable xml file. You can use the accentColor inside your drawable file.

For example

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerY="0.3"
    android:startColor="@color/accent"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: In your example it creates a gradient.

Comment: Would be helpful to know what exactly is the scrim_background.

Comment: it's a drawable resource file. I will edit the question.

Comment: I digged around. Seems no simple way of doing it in pure xml. You reminded me why I started hating android.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent()`?

```
int setAlphaComponent (int color, int alpha)
```

You could query any color with:

```
int x = getColor(R.color.yourColor)
```

Then create any alpha version of that color with:

```
int newX = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(x, newAlpha);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that programmatically using:

```
textView.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
```

Comment: I think it works, but I'd like to add it to the style otherwise e will have to find all TextViews and this code to each one.

Comment: A solution could be to create a custom view AlphaTextView that extends TextView, in which you change the background alpha.

Comment: Yes, it is a solution. But I think should be a way to do it via resouces.